# Can I make a multi-select custom member field?

Tags: members, custom-fields

It looks like you can only make a few custom member field types: Date, Text Input, Textarea, Select Dropdown, URL.

I need to have a multi-select field, such as checkboxes.

What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The options for custom member fields are currently fairly limited.  I believe that in time improvements to the member features of EE will appear, and possibly when they do this constraint will go away.  Until then the most common solution is to set up a separate channel to hold member data that won't fit into the available member fields.  You can set up the channel with all the fields you need, and include in the entry a field to capture the member id each entry relates to - then retrieve this information using the member ID as and when you need it.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can go for [Smart Members PRO](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-members-pro) which allows you to create custom members field like Date, Text Input, Textarea, Select Dropdown and many more. I hope this plugin will fulfils your all requirement of multi-select. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both good options, above. I did something perhaps creative, perhaps stupid, but definitely desperate: Because checkboxes are binary selections, I used a Select Dropdown for each "checkbox" with a Yes/No option. Works OK for a small amount.